# How to implement SKActionTimingFunction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

How do you implement SKActionTimingFunction in objective-c?. I've looked everywhere and I just found an example in swift.

Thanks!

Comment: It is just a block that accepts a float between 0 and 1 and returns a float between 0 and 1 - what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

heres an example

```
moveAction.timingFunction = ^float(float t){
    return sin(t * M_PI/2);
};
```

man i hate blocks in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4.2:**

```
moveAction.timingFunction = { time -> Float in
    return sin(time * .pi/2)
}
```