# EaseOut action with custom SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have the following custom SKAction working but as an EaseIn instead EaseOut. I want it to EaseOut! I have failed miserably to correct it using various easing equations found around the web.

```
    let duration = 2.0
    let initialX = cameraNode.position.x
    let customEaseOut = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(duration, actionBlock: {node, elapsedTime in

        let t = Double(elapsedTime)/duration
        let b = Double(initialX)
        let c = Double(targetPoint.x)
        let p = t*t*t*t*t

        let l = b*(1-p) + c*p

        node.position.x = CGFloat(l)
    })

    cameraNode.runAction(customEaseOut)
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify the following code to allow the custom action to ease-out instead of ease-in

```
let t = Double(elapsedTime)/duration
...
let p = t*t*t*t*t
```

To get a better understanding of `p`, it is helpful to plot it as a function of `t`

[image]

Clearly, the function eases in over time. Changing the definition of `t` to

```
let t = 1 - Double(elapsedTime)/duration
```

and plotting `p` gives

[image]

The action now eases out, but it starts at 1 and ends at 0. To resolve this, change the definition of `p` to

```
let p = 1-t*t*t*t*t
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How did you draw these curves?

Comment: @Confused I used Numbers

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to calculate it.

`SKAction` just have a property called `timingMode`:

```
// fall is an SKAction
fall.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
```

You can choose from:

- linear (default)
- easeIn
- easeOut
- easeInEaseOut

Check details from [API docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417807-timingmode) and also [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skactiontimingmode).

If you need to change the Apple presets you can use: [timingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skactiontimingfunction)

```
fall.timingFunction = { time -> Float in
    return time
}
```

To build a custom function according to the source:

```
/**
 A custom timing function for SKActions. Input time will be linear 0.0-1.0
 over the duration of the action. Return values must be 0.0-1.0 and increasing
 and the function must return 1.0 when the input time reaches 1.0.
 */
public typealias SKActionTimingFunction = (Float) -> Float
```

So with these informations you can write:

```
func CubicEaseOut(_ t:Float)->Float
{
   let f:Float = (t - 1);
   return f * f * f + 1;
}
fall.timingFunction = CubicEaseOut
```

Comment: In some ways you're right. But it looks like the OP is after a much stronger curve than the presets from Apple.

Comment: Hi Confused, thank you for you comment. So, why don't try to use it : timingFunction?(https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skactiontimingfunction?) an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28521379/1894067

Comment: because I'm not the OP ;).  More seriously, I'm busily adopting some of these, for what I'm doing: https://github.com/craiggrummitt/SpriteKitEasingSwift and coming to terms with the "powers" of SKActions. I don't fully understand their range of customisation options yet. I tend to think much more in terms of physics and keyframes. Never really liked Actions and their way of thinking. but starting to come around on their usefulness, a little.

Comment: I can see one reason to not use the timingFunction: it's (seemingly) changing the relative time of events through the range of a duration rather than the position during time steps. For most visual thinkers, this playing with time stretching is harder to conceive of and incorporate into a mental model than position curves changing over equal time steps. The graphs in Epsilon's answer come naturally to this kind of thinking. I think.

Comment: But I can sort of see that playing with time could get the same results. Just harder to visualise which changes what, when and how. And why.

Comment: Sorry for the spamminess, but the more I think about the SKActionTimingFunction, the more I see it might be quite powerful. And elegant. The maths of using it are a little beyond me. I need something visual to draw out the desired curves.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added also some examples to my answer. You can easily build these function with few lines, only changing time, your project in link follow the same rules, good luck man : https://github.com/craiggrummitt/SpriteKitEasingSwift/blob/master/Pod/Classes/easing.swift

Comment: Argh, that additional code is awesome. I was just getting some stuff together to ask you about how to do this. Here's a site to see how the curves make motion very different: http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,1,0,1

Comment: This stops working at four (f * f * f * f + 1).. it's still not quite as tight as I'd like. Is there a way to get a tighter/stronger curve?

Comment: How do I apply this to something like the width of a line of an SKShapeNode?

Comment: And in this line `func CubicEaseOut(_ t:Float)->Float` what is t, and what are its possible range of values and their impact?

Comment: A timingMode define the behaviour of a SKAction. You speak about an object (SKShapeNode ) and ask to have the same behaviour about a line. If I' ve understand this is not possible.

Comment: In this answer, it seems possible to use "blocks" or "closures" or whatever they are called to make changes to SKShapeNode properties, but I don't understand how to put it all together with custom actions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072071/resize-sprite-without-shrinking-contents/40073252#40073252

Comment: And this comes close, it provides a float that changes over time, but I can't see how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284692/skease-action-how-to-use-float-changing-action-setter-block

Comment: Oh yes, but there is always an action involved , in this case is "resize", and they don't speak about spriteNode but shapeNode. Basically, timingMode define the action behavior during time, then if you want to build a shape or resize a sprite you could do it but timingMode change only the SKAction, it's not applicable directly to an object.

Comment: DOH! How do I use the CGFloat animation that comes from the SKEase facilities in the question here, in a way it impacts a property of an SKShapeNode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284692/skease-action-how-to-use-float-changing-action-setter-block

Comment: If you want to "give a timingMode animation" to a SKShapeNode construction, you could start from the shape foundation: point and line. For example if I want to build a rectangle I can draw lines to construct sides inside a block defined by a customAction, After, I can change timingMode about this SKAction. You should this because to the init methods about SKSpriteNode or SKShapeNode you haven't timingMode definition to control the build animation.

Comment: Not to the construction, I want to provide a very strong easing curve to the animation of changes to the lineWidth of a ShapeNode

Comment: If you have a SKAction that define this change , yes you can do it.

Comment: If a method dont exist, you should re-create it starting from dots or use methods that give you the final result :-)